# Filter an array against another array/string conditionally in Ramda

Tags: javascript, filter, functional-programming, ramda.js

I am practising Ramda, and trying to construct a function as follows:

the function takes two args:

```
userInput: {
  query: Array[String] || String,
  target: Array[String]
}
```

goal:

- filter the target array and return a new array meeting certain criteria
- criteria being the new array should only consist of strings that are starting with the given queries.

For example:
if the target being:

```
["pen", "pencil", "paper", "", undefined, True, "books", "paperback"]
```

and the query being:

```
["pen", "paper"]
```

then the filtered result should be:

```
["pen", "pencil", "paper", "paperback"]
```

I have achieved the goal in a normal/vanilla(?) js way. But that was not necessarily FP, nor was it utilising Ramda.

My experiment so far has been like this:

- iterate the query Array (if it is an array, or just plain string), and check the target against each query (using `startsWith` from Ramda);
- return true/false whether the target string meets any of the criteria (using `any` or `anyPass` from Ramda);
- filter the whole array based on the T/F value from the step above;

When it comes to code, I am thinking of using `map` or `apply` to apply that `startsWith` function to each element of the target array. So far I have only done this:

```
const textStartsWith = curry((query, target) =>
  pipe(toString, startsWith(query))(target)
);
```

However, I am stuck here with currying the composition of functions.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would combine `startsWith` and `anyPass` like this:

```js
const textStartsWith = pipe (
  map (startsWith), 
  anyPass,
  flip (o) (String),
  filter
)

console .log (
  textStartsWith 
    (['pen', 'paper']) 
    (['pen', 'pencil', 'paper', '', undefined, true, 'books', 'paperback'])
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script>const {pipe, map, startsWith, anyPass, flip, o, filter} = R </script>
```

If you want to be able to pass the arguments in one go, you can just wrap this up in `uncurry`:

```
const textStartsWith = uncurryN (2) (pipe (
  map (startsWith), 
  anyPass,
  flip (o) (String),
  filter
))

textStartsWith (query, target)
```

This does point out a missing function in Ramda, I think.  Ramda has variadic `compose` and `pipe` functions, and a curried binary compose, `o`.  But there's no equivalent curried binary `pipe`.

### If you read Haskell

One possible way to arrive at such an implementation is to make a fully curried function, and then paste a Haskell equivalent into http://pointfree.io.

So if we started with this function:

```js
const f1 = (query) => (target) => filter (pipe (
  String, 
  anyPass (map( startsWith) (query))
)) (target)
```

We can make a Haskell version like this:

```hs
\query -> \target -> filter ((anyPass ((map startsWith) query)) . string) target
```

which then returns this:

```hs
filter . (. string) . anyPass . map startsWith
```

which we can convert back into JS like the first answer above by noting that `foo . bar` is the composition of `foo` and `bar` and that `(. foo)` is equivalent to `flip (o) (foo)` or `o (__, foo)`

And we can end up with something like the first snippet above.

### Update

User Kuncheria asked about `flip (o) (String)`.  Perhaps a walk through the signatures might help.  We pass four functions to pipe.

**`map (startsWith)`** has the signature `[String] -> [(String -> Boolean)]`.  It takes a list of Strings and returns a list of functions from String to Boolean.

**`anyPass`** has the signature `[(a -> Boolean)] -> (a -> Boolean)`.  It takes a list of functions from some arbitrary type, `a` to `Boolean` and returns a single function from an `a` to `Boolean` (which will be `true` exactly when at least one of those functions return true for the `a` supplied.)

Now we can combine the output of `map (startsWith)` (`[(String -> Boolean)]` with the input to `anyPass`, by substituting `String` for `a`, and so `pipe (map (startsWith), anyPass))` has the signature `[String] -> (String -> Boolean)`.

**`flip (o) (String)`** is the most complex function here, and we'll explain it below.  There we'll find out that its type is `(String -> c) -> (a -> c)`.

And now substituting `Boolean` for `c`, we combine with the above to to see that `pipe (map (startsWith), anyPass, flip (o) (String))` has the signature `[String] -> (a -> Boolean)`.

**`filter`** simply has the signature `(a -> Boolean) -> [a] -> [a]`.  It accepts a function that transforms a value of type `a` into a boolean, and returns a function that takes a list of values of type `a` and returns the filtered list of those for which the function returns `true`.

So combining this with the above, we can note that our main function -- `pipe (map (startsWith), anyPass, flip (o) (String), filter)` -- has the signature `[String] -> [a] -> [a]`

We might write the above discussion more compactly like this:

```js
const textStartsWith = pipe (
  map (startsWith),    // [String] -> [(String -> Boolean)]
  anyPass,             // [(a -> Boolean)] -> (a -> Boolean)
     // a = String  =>    [String] -> (String -> Boolean)
  flip (o) (String),   // (String -> c) -> (a -> c)
     // c = Boolean =>    [String] -> (a -> Boolean) 
  filter               // (a -> Boolean) -> [a] -> [a]
     //             =>    [String] -> [a] -> [a]
)
```

But we still need to discuss `flip (o) (String)`.

**`o`** is a curried binary `compose` function, whose signature is

```hs
o :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)
```

We can `flip` it, to get:

```hs
flip (o) :: (a -> b) -> (b -> c) -> (a -> c)
```

Now we run into a notational problem.  We've been using `String` to denote the String type.  But in JS, `String` is also a function: constructing a String out of any value.  We can think of it as the function from some type `a` to a String, that is with type `a -> String`.  So, since

```hs
flip (o) :: (a -> b) -> (b -> c) -> (a -> c)
```

We can see this:

```hs
flip (o) (String)
;            ^----------------- Constructor function
flip (o) (a -> String)
;                 ^------------ Data type
flip (o) (String) :: (String -> c) -> (a -> c)
;            ^           ^----- Data type
;            +----------------- Constructor function
```

We can think of `flip (o) (String)` as a function that accepts a function which transforms a String into type `c`, and returns a function which transforms something of type `a` into something of type `c`.  An example would be `length`, the function which takes the length of a string:

```js
const strLength = flip (o) (String) (length)
strLength ('abc')  //=> 3  because String ('abc') = 'abc'
strLength (42)     //=> 2  because String (42) = '42'
strLength (void 0) //=> 9  because String (void 0) = 'undefined'
strLength ({})     //=> 15 because String ({}) = 'object [Object]'
```

Comment: Interesting solution, but what is the purpose of `flip (o) (String)` here

Comment: @Kuncheria: Added an explanation of that to the question.

Comment: It is super clear now, thanks :) One last question, in your explanation about `anyPass` its mentioned that `anyPass` will give a function that returns `true` when all its input predicates are `true`. Shouldn't it return `true` when at least one predicates resolves to `true`.

Comment: @Kuncheria: absolutely!  Fixed.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If `query` is not an array, convert it to an array (see `convertToArray`). Map the `query`, and create an array of tests using `R.startsWith`. Filter the `target`, and use `R.anyPass` as the predicate:

```js
const { curry, unless, is, of, filter, anyPass, map, startsWith } = R;

const convertToArray = unless(is(Array), of);

const textStartsWith = curry((query, target) =>
  filter(anyPass(map(startsWith, convertToArray(query))))(target)
);

const query = ["pen", "paper"];
const target = ["pen", "pencil", "paper", "", "books", "paperback"];

const result = textStartsWith(query, target);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.js" integrity="sha512-3sdB9mAxNh2MIo6YkY05uY1qjkywAlDfCf5u1cSotv6k9CZUSyHVf4BJSpTYgla+YHLaHG8LUpqV7MHctlYzlw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

If you need to handle non string values, I would return `false` for every value, which is not a string. Note that convert a string using `R.toString` would transform the string - `R.toString('abc'); //=> '"abc"'`  (see [docs](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#toString))

```js
const { curry, unless, is, of, filter, ifElse, anyPass, map, startsWith, always } = R;

const convertToArray = unless(is(Array), of);

const textStartsWith = curry((query, target) =>
  filter(ifElse(
    is(String),
    anyPass(map(startsWith, convertToArray(query))),
    always(false)
  ))(target)
);

const query = ["pen", "paper"];
const target = ["pen", "pencil", "paper", "", undefined, true, "books", "paperback"];

const result = textStartsWith(query, target);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.js" integrity="sha512-3sdB9mAxNh2MIo6YkY05uY1qjkywAlDfCf5u1cSotv6k9CZUSyHVf4BJSpTYgla+YHLaHG8LUpqV7MHctlYzlw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```